# I can't read a file with ifstream in a build, but can read it in an IDE

Tags: c++, file-io, ifstream

When I run a program in Eclipse which is supposed to read a file and output its contents to the console, it reads it and outputs it without any problems, but when I build it and run it outside of the IDE it doesn't read it.

This is the code that reads the file:

```
Map::Map(std::string file, SE_Graphics *graphics) {
    std::ifstream input(file);

    if (input.is_open()) {
        std::string line;
        while (std::getline(input, line)) {
            std::cout << line << std::flush;
        }
        input.close();
    } else {
        std::cout << "File is missing" << std::flush;
    }
}
```

And this is how I call the method:

```
Map map("salsaboy/maps/test.sem", se.getGraphics());
```

This is the folder structure:

```
Lab (the build)
src
salsaboy
|-tiles
|-maps
  |-test.sem
```

Every time I run it outside of the IDE it just says `File is missing`, even when I try to write to that file `input.is_open()` isn't true.

Comment: Up for just 3 minutes and already a dislike without context. At least tell me what's wrong with the question!

Comment: . o O ( "`if (input.is_open()) { stuff; stuff; stuff; stuff; stuff; stuff; more_stuff; } else get_the_hell_outa_here();`" ... why do people do something like that? ... `if(!input.is_open()) get_the_hell_outa_here(); stuff; stuff; stuff; stuff; stuff; stuff; more_stuff;` )

Comment: Where are you running it when outside of the IDE?

Comment: Are you sure the current working directory is `/wher/ever/Lab` when you run the program?

Comment: @Swordfish That's just how I do it. It's like putting braces on the same line or on different lines.

Comment: @Swordfish the working directory should be where the file is, right?

Comment: @LukePasfield Usually, yes, unless you're using the command prompt to run it. So is the file you're running in the Lab directory?

Comment: @immibis No. In the question, I have the folder layout.

Comment: @LukePasfield So where is the file you're running? I don't see it in the folder layout in the question.

Comment: @immibis The test.sem file at the bottom.

Comment: @Luke We are interested in three locations: 1. Where the executable file is located, 2. from which folder you are calling the executable file and 3. where test.sem is located. Actually your question answers only q3

Comment: @rbf The executable is the Lab file, I'm just running the executable, test.sem is there. But anyway, I've fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only to do this that I can see is by getting the whole file path from the executable's directory, cutting out the file, and replacing that with the file path I want.